# send and retrieve url parameters using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two HTML pages. I am trying to send parameters to the second URL from the first URL using **window.location.href**

The code I have tried is:

me1.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="redirectPage();">
<script>
    function redirectPage(){
        var a = "me";
        var b = "here";
        var url = "me2.html?a="+String(a)+"&b="+String(b);
        window.location.href = url;
    }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

me2.html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body onload="getValues();">
<script>
    function getValues(){
        var a,b;
        var SearchString = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var VariableArray = SearchString.split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < VariableArray.length; i++){
            var KeyValuePair = VariableArray[i].split('=');
            if(KeyValuePair[0] == "a"){
                a = KeyValuePair[1];
                console.log("CUSTOMER KEY: "+a);
                alert("A: "+String(a));
            }
            else if(KeyValuePair[0] == "b"){
                b = KeyValuePair[1];
                console.log("USER KEY: "+String(b));
                alert("B: "+b);
            }

    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't get any alerts, though the URL formed is correct. 
what may be the issue with the code?

Comment: What does your console say? [Hint: F12 to see your console]

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: getValues is not defined

Comment: I think your function is not being recognized. At least it looks that way from the error. Maybe you missed on some "Curly Bracket". Let me run this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried your code and it was almost working. You forgot a `}`

```
function getValues(){
    var a,b;
    var SearchString = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var VariableArray = SearchString.split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < VariableArray.length; i++){
        var KeyValuePair = VariableArray[i].split('=');
        if(KeyValuePair[0] == "a"){
            a = KeyValuePair[1];
            console.log("CUSTOMER KEY: "+a);
            alert("A: "+String(a));
        }
        else if(KeyValuePair[0] == "b"){
            b = KeyValuePair[1];
            console.log("USER KEY: "+String(b));
            alert("B: "+b);
        }
    } // you forgot to close the for loop here
}
```

Now it is alerting: *A: me* and *B: here*.

Comment: that's stupid of me. probably JS gets that out in me..:D
thanks a lot for the answer..:)

Comment: Yes this is the exact answer. @user2739737 you can mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code.

**me.html**

```
var a = "me",
    b = "here",
    url = "";

url = "me2.html?a=" + a + "&b=" + b;
window.location.href = url;
```

**me2.html**

```
var url,
    params,
    paramArr,
    keyVal;

url = window.location.href;
params = url.split("?")[1];
paramArr = params.split("&");

for(var i=0; i<paramArr.length; i++){
   keyVal = paramArr[i].split("=");
   alert("Key: " + keyVal[0] + ", Value: " + keyVal[1]);
}
```